# Nhibernate xml mapping to relationship tables

Tags: many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following situation that at first view is a many to many case.

```
TABLE TExam
(
    IdExam
    ...
) 

TABLE TExamContent
(
    IdExam,
    IdContent
)

TABLE TContent
(
    IdContent,
    ...
)
```

But I need the table TExamContent just because the table TContent is attachments of the whole system, so I can't put the TExam foreign key on it.

For these tables I have (or I want to) the following classes, but I don't need the Content contains a list of Exams. Actually, my content will have only one Exam (it's a workaround that I can't change)

How do I map these tables to this classes so that my Exam class have a List of Content like ?

```
    public class Exam
    {
       public int IdExam{get;set;}
       public IList<Content> ContentList { get; set; }
    } 

    public class Content
    {
        IdContent,
        ...
    }
```

I think if I can't do this I need to do the following, don't I?

```
public class Exam
{
   public int IdExam{get;set;}
   public IList<ExamContent> IdExam{get;set;}

}

public class ExamContent
{
    public int IdExam {get;set;},
    public int IdContent {get;set;}
}

public class Content{
    public int IdContent,
    ...
}
```

In this case I want my ExamContent class have only the the references to Exam class and Content class, not its key as following.

```
public class ExamContent
{
    public Exam Exam {get;set;}
    public Content  Content {get;set;}
}
```

How should I make this mapping?

Currently this is my mapping

```
<class name="MedicalCertificateContent" lazy="true" table="TExamContent">

    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="IdExam" type="Int32">
        <column name="IdExam" not-null="true" precision="10" scale="0" sql-type="int" />
      </key-property>
      <key-property name="IdContent" type="Guid">
        <column name="IdContent" not-null="true" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" />
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>

    <many-to-one name="Content" class="Content" fetch="join" not-null="true" column="IdContent" lazy="proxy" />

    <many-to-one name="Exam" class="Exam" fetch="join" not-null="true" column="IdContent" lazy="proxy"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem doing this is that I need to save the exam to add content later.
I want to create my Exam, add the content an the save everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple many-to-many. Roughly like this:

```
<class name="Exam" table="TExam">
  <id ...>

  <bag name="ContentList" table="TExamContent">
    <key column="IdExam"/>
    <many-to-many class="Content">
      <column name="IdContent"/>
    </many-to-many>
  </bag>

</class>

<class name="Content" table="TContent">
  <id ..>

</class>
```